# Magento 2.3.1 : how to get custom options html with price variation assigned to it?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2

> I tried with this code

```
public function getCustomOptionsHtml($product)
{

    $_product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product);
    $layout = $this->layoutFactory->create();

    $blockOptionData = $layout->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options")->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml');

    $block_links1 = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType', 'default')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml');
    $blockOptionData->setChild('default', $block_links1);


    $option_price_renderer_block = $layout
            ->createBlock(
                    "Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render", "product.price.render.default", [
                'data' => [
                    'price_render_handle' => 'catalog_product_prices',
                    'use_link_for_as_low_as' => 'false'
                ]
                    ]
            )
            ->setData('area', 'frontend');

    $option_price_renderer_block->setProduct($_product);
    $blockOptionData->setChild('product.price.render.default', $option_price_renderer_block);


    $block_links2 = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text', 'text')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml');
    $blockOptionData->setChild('text', $block_links2);


    $block_links3 = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File', 'file')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml');
    $blockOptionData->setChild('file', $block_links3);

    $block_links4 = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select', 'select')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml');
    $blockOptionData->setChild('select', $block_links4);

    $block_links5 = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date', 'date')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml');
    $blockOptionData->setChild('date', $block_links5);

    return $blockOptionData->toHtml();


}
```

> show error like this
>
> > Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function renderAmount()
> >     on boolean in
> >     /home/userdrive/www/magentoproject/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/AbstractOptions.php:161
> >     Stack trace:
> >      /home/userdrive/www/magentoproject/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select/Multiple.php(95):
> >     Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions->_formatPrice(Array,
> >     false)
> >      /home/userdrive/www/magentoproject/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select/Multiple.php(43):
> >     Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select\Multiple->processSelectOption(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select),
> >     Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option))
> >      /home/manishm/www/magentoproject/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php(79):
> >     Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select\Multiple->_toHtml()
> >      /home/userdrive/www/magentoproject/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/type/select.phtml(21):
> >     Magento in
> >     /home/userdrive/www/magentoproject/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/AbstractOptions.php
> >     on line 161

Comment: In Magento 2.3 working fine.

Comment: In Magento 2.3.0 working fine. but not working in 2.3.1 & 2.3.2

Comment: @DivyeshRana did you find any solution? How did you fix this?